# Attribute error: module 'teradatasql' has no attribute 'connect' please solve this error

Tags: python-3.x

import teradatasql as tds
import pandas as pd

with tds.connect(None,host='',user='',password='
') as connect:
cursor=connect.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("create volatile table voltab (c1 integer, c2 varchar(100)) on commit preserve rows")

```
cursor.execute ("insert into voltab (?, ?)", [
        [1, "abc"],
        [2, "def"],
        [3, "ghi"]])

cursor.execute ("select * from voltab order by 1")
[ print (row) for row in cur.fetchall () ]
connect.commit()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ttt.py", line 4, in 
with tds.connect(None,host='',user='',paasword='') as connect:
AttributeError: module 'teradatasql' has no attribute 'connect'

Comment: i am import the teradatasql also but i got this error Attribute error: module 'teradatasql' has no attribute 'connect' please solve this error

Answer (score 0):

The only syntax problem that I found in your program was "cur.fetchall" which instead should be "cursor.fetchall" because your variable is named "cursor".

Here is the corrected program which I ran:

```
import teradatasql as tds
import pandas as pd
with tds.connect(None, host="whomooz", user="guest", password="please") as connect:
 cursor=connect.cursor ()
 cursor.execute ("create volatile table voltab (c1 integer, c2 varchar(100)) on commit preserve rows")
 cursor.execute ("insert into voltab (?, ?)", [
  [1, "abc"],
  [2, "def"],
  [3, "ghi"]])
 cursor.execute ("select * from voltab order by 1")
 [ print (row) for row in cursor.fetchall () ]
 connect.commit()
```

and I got the following successful output:

```
[1, 'abc']
[2, 'def']
[3, 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to name the Python file the same as any of the modules being imported in that Python file.

i read from:
https://geektechstuff.com/2020/06/13/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-has-no-attribute-python/